# SELECT total from two different table in mysql but getting different answer

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, rows

I got a problem in my code where I started to get lost. My coding shows the different result in `MySQL and website display`.

this is my code, I query it in `MySQL database,` it fetches the `total of student + employer = 1341`. But when I wrote in PHP, it displays the total of 1 on the website. why is this happen? For information, both codes below here are the function in MySQL but not displaying right amount on the website.

Am I missing something? I'm still learning the right way to query.

**First code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', '', 'dashboard');

$stddboard = $conn ->query ("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student) + (SELECT 
COUNT(*) FROM employer) FROM dual");
$totstddboard = mysqli_num_rows($stddboard);
?>

<?php echo mysqli_num_rows($stddboard) ?>
```

**Second code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', '', 'dashboard');

$stddboard = $conn ->query ("SELECT  ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student) + 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employer) 
     ) AS 'Column' ");
$totstddboard = mysqli_num_rows($stddboard);
?>

<?php echo mysqli_num_rows($stddboard) ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysqli_num_rows` returns the number of rows that are returned. The `count()` function returns 1 row with a count of the matching rows in it. So what you really need to do is [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) your result object. For code block 1 you'd use:

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', '', 'dashboard');

$stddboard = $conn ->query ("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student) + (SELECT 
COUNT(*) FROM employer) as da_count FROM dual");
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$totstddboard = $row['da_count'];
echo $totstddboard;
?>
```